# How to install Sublime 3 on CentOS 7 / RHEL 7?

Tags: php, linux, installation, sublimetext3, developer-tools

Sublime is really cool. Loved the slick user interface, a perfect developer environment and an amazing performance. Today I was re-installing the sublime as my OS has some problem. Thought to share the steps to install the Sublime, as this is a great tool for developers- Its really a editor which you’ll fall in love with.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are the Steps: 
**Step 1: Download Sublime:** 
You can either download from their website or use the wget as I did:

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
## On 32bit
$ wget https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3126_x32.tar.bz2

## On 64bit
$ wget https://download.sublimetext.com/sublime_text_3_build_3126_x64.tar.bz2
```

**Step 2. Extract Sublime package (example to /opt directory)**  
You can store Sublime at any place you want. Here, I saved under /opt directory.

```
## On 32bit
$ sudo tar -vxjf sublime_text_3_build_3126_x32.tar.bz2 -C /opt
## On 64bit
$ sudo tar -vxjf sublime_text_3_build_3126_x64.tar.bz2 -C /opt
```

**Step 3. Now, let’s make a symbolic link to the installed Sublime3 so that we can run the same from command line**

```
# sudo ln -s /opt/sublime_text_3/sublime_text /usr/bin/sublime3
```

**Step 4. Now, let’s test whether the Sublime3 is installed correctly or not.**  
Type sublime3 in command line and it will open up the sublime window.

```
$ sublime3
```

**Step 5. Create Gnome desktop launcher You can run Sublime3 on desktop by clicking a icon.**

```
$ sudo sublime3 /usr/share/applications/sublime3.desktop
```

**Step 6. Append this and close file.**

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Sublime3
Exec=sublime3
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/sublime_text_3/Icon/48x48/sublime-text.png
Type=Application
Categories=TextEditor;IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=sublime -n
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Now, you can see the Sublime3 icon on under Applications → Programming. 
 You can run Sublime3 on desktop by clicking this icon. Enjoy!!

Answer (score 4):

To install sublime on CentOS, RHEL and older version of Fedora, run the following commands-

```
sudo rpm -v --import https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-rpm-pub.gpg

sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.sublimetext.com/rpm/stable/x86_64/sublime-text.repo

sudo yum install sublime-text
```

Sublime is Installed

```
# Check the version of Sublime 

subl --version
```

Hope this works!!!

Comment: Thanks, this way make sence

Answer (score 0):

Enter into SU then copy and paste into terminal.

rpm -v --import https://download.sublimetext.com/sublimehq-rpm-pub.gpg && yum update && yum install yum-utils -y && sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.sublimetext.com/rpm/stable/x86_64/sublime-text.repo && yum update && yum install sublime-text -y